# Is it possible to share datasource testcontainer between quarkus apps in dev mode?

Tags: datasource, quarkus, testcontainers

For kafka, redis and other testcontainer services there is a quarkus.*.devservices.shared configuration option (e.g. https://quarkus.io/guides/dev-services#quarkus-kafka-client-config-group-kafka-dev-services-build-time-config_quarkus.kafka.devservices.shared), which will reuse testcontainers of that type if there is already an existing one running.

Is there a way to achieve something similar with datasources/dbs?

Example:
I have two quarkus apps and I want to share a mysql db between them in dev mode. Setting up the tables is done with flyway.

Comment: AFAIK this is not currently possible, but it would be a nice feature. Please open a Github issue

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have opened an issue for this https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26215